# What is more common: X_train or x_train?

Tags: python, pep8

What is more common: X_train or x_train? In keras documentation I see 'x_train', while sklearn documentation usually contains 'X_train'. Is there any standard on the notation?

Comment: "What is more common" is almost an entirely subjective question. "Is there a standard" is an objective one (to which the answer is evidently "no", as you've shown in your examples).

Answer (score 1):

`x_train` for variable names (lowercase and snakecase)

Answer (score 0):

If you go into statistics behind it usually the hypothesis equation used is
`Y = f(x)`, where Y is the output and f(x) is the function of all variables used in the equation

Hence `x_train`, `Y_train`
. But as you said there is a difference in libraries and there is not compulsion to use one or the other.

Comment: Is there any common example that uses lowercase x and uppercase Y?

Answer (score 0):

The question should not be about "more common", but what is represented in `X_train`. It is a capital letter X to represent a 2-D matrix.

Mathematically, it is a common notation for Linear Algebra to use uppercase Latin letters for matrices (e.g. matrix X) and lowercase Latin letters for vectors (vector y).

In data science, the feature matrix `X` is a collection of many columns of feature values. For example a `df` with 1 target, 20 features and 1000 data records will have the shape of shape (1000, 21). So we will define the feature matrix `X` to have the shape (1000, 20). Whereas the target label `y` is a column of values having the shape (1000, 1).

After applying `train_test_split()` on `X` and `y` with `test_size=0.25`, I would expect:
`X_train` to be a 2-D matrix (750, 20)
`y_train` to be a 1-D vector (750, 1)